# Dynamic arrays vs. std::vector

Tags: c++, performance, stdvector, dynamic-arrays

I've written a small program to calculate prime numbers using the naive division algorithm. In order to improve the performance, I thought it should only check the divisibility based on previously detected primes less than equal to the number's square root.
In order to do that, I need to keep track of the primes. I've implemented it using dynamic arrays. (e.g. Using `new` and `delete`). Should I use `std::vector` instead? Which is better in terms of performance? (Maintenance is not an issue.)
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A `std::vector` is simply a wrapper around a dynamic array.

Comment: So, I think using the dynamic arrays directly would be neater. Right?

Comment: In general I would use arrays with `new[]` and `delete[]` only if my purpose was to study how they work, which is always useful if you have to deal with legacy code, e.g. libraries written in plain C. For every other case, go with `std::vectors`. They are efficient enough that you almost never have to worry about it.

Comment: Actually, I'm just a math enthusiast (rather, student) who's learning c++ for fun. No intentions to give it to anyone besides some friends. So, what would you suggest in that case? @ Fabio

Comment: If you are new to C++ and want to experiment: First implement your algorithm with new / delete. You will probably see that you have to be very careful not produce a memory leak. Then use std::vector and you will not only learn how to use it, but also to appreciate how much easier it is to work with it rather then with raw arrays.

Comment: If you don't want to use `std::vector` then use `std::unique_ptr` with `new/new[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The ideal answer:**

How should any of us know?  It depends on your compiler, your OS, your architecture, your standard library implementation, the alignment of the planets...

Benchmark it.  Possibly with [this](https://github.com/google/benchmark).  (Haven't used it, but it seems simple enough to use.)

**The practical answer:**

Use `std::vector`.  Every `new` and `delete` you make is a chance for a memory leak, or a double-`delete`, or otherwise forgetting to do something.  `std::vector` basically does this under the hood anyway.  You're more likely to get a sizeable performance boost by maxing out your optimization flags (if you're using `gcc`, try `-Ofast` and `-march=native`).

Also:

> Maintenance is not an issue.

Doubt it.  Trust me on this one.  If nothing else, at least comment your code (but that's another can of worms).

Comment: 'Maintenance is not an issue.' - please, please come and do my job.

Comment: As I've said in the comments, I'm learning c++ just for fun... So, really, maintainance is not an issue. No one besides some of my friends is ever gonna use it.

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose, vector might be better, so that you don't need to worry about memory management (e.g. grow your array size and copy previous results), or reserve too much memory to store your results.

Comment: Actually, reserving too much memory or growing the array size is not of concern. As they are easily comparable using the given inputs.